# Java / Eclipse Debug view issue

Tags: java, eclipse

Im having issues with the Debug view in Eclipse.
I've set the options to show popup and suspend execution on both handled and unhandled exceptions (Preferences > Java > Debug), however when an exception is thrown, i just get the stack trace printed in the console without the actual debug breakpoint appearing. I have tried adding a breakpoint for all subclasses of `RuntimeException` but that just creates a mess.

In short, is there any way that when an exception is thrown, to create a breakpoint on that line and give variable / expression information ?

Comment: yeah you can catch your exceptions and print out your own information in a try/catch.

Comment: in eclipse debugger you can create special breakpoints to break on specific exceptions caught and uncaughy

Comment: Make sure you start the program with a Debug, not a Run, launcher.

Comment: As i said, i have tried adding certain exceptions to the breakpoints tab, but then the app crashes because of an error in a class i didn't even reference (when running / debugging without those breakpoints, the app runs just fine !)